# Is it possible to add buttons with links in a Facebook post?

Tags: javascript, facebook

Dear friends / colleagues:
I've been thinking about adding one or two buttons (each with a link) to a Facebook post with an image.
I would like to know if this can be done, and if possible help me with the code.
Of course, I appreciate your attention.

Comment: It's possible to add the main image, which in itself links to somewhere, though you cannot have two images on the same page. If you want multiple links, you'll need to reference them as standard `<a href>` text links.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I'm confused by your comment. I'm not aware of Facebook permitting HTML in post messages at all.